# Getting error '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'startswith' while uploading local image on a webhook's avatar

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I I'm trying to use a local image as a webhook's avatar as a webhook, webhooks don't allow image links as an avatar but using a local image gives me error: `'_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'startswith'`, here below is my scrip

As using a link as an avatar isn't allowed (I think this because when i use an image link i get error: TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes) I tried to use a local file using `with open` but I'm just getting more errors!

```
@bot.command()
async def whook(ctx):
    with open("image.png", 'rb') as pfp:
        await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name="Mr.W.hook",avatar=pfp)
        await ctx.send("Done")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the **data** of the avatar image, as a `bytes` object, not the file object that contains the data. The exception is thrown because the `create_webhook()` code tries to use the [`bytes.startswith()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.startswith) on the `pfp` object you passed in, and file objects don't have that method.

Instead of `pfp` itself, pass in the result of `pfp.read()`. This returns the image data as a `bytes` value:

```
with open("image.png", 'rb') as pfp:
    await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name="Mr.W.hook", avatar=pfp.read())
    await ctx.send("Done")
```

From the [`discord.TextChannel.create_webhook()` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_webhook):

> `avatar` (`Optional[bytes]`) – A bytes-like object representing the webhook’s default avatar.

Comment: Much appreciations!